# How i can transfer same driver components across all pages in selenium with POM and Testng

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, pom.xml

Normally i am creating multiple page repository and one test page.If i want to create multiple test page, ie each test page for each page repository, then how can i transfer driver widgets across different test pages.

Answer (score 0):

You may introduce base classes which will contain the common elements that are shared across multiple pages.

The same goes for the methods that are using them.

Can you specify the language you're using in other to get a more specific answer?

Comment: After declaring base class, i have to extend that one in all pages, right? i am using java language

Comment: Yes, you may also look at the page/object pattern which will solve for you structure of base elements and methods (https://www.automatetheplanet.com/page-object-pattern/ - this is done in C#, but the translation to Java is as easy as to replace the system keywords)

Answer (score 0):

Try with PageObject pattern. 
here is an example how driver is being instantiated and transfer throughout code, and this is best practice for automating:

```
public class LoginPage {

private WebDriver driver;

@FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="username")
private WebElement txtUsername;

@FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="butonSubmit")
private WebElement buttonSubmit;


public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {           
         this.driver = driver; 
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}

public void inputUsername(String username){
    txtUsername.sendKeys(username);
    return this;
}

public void clickSubmit(String username){
    buttonSubmit.click();
    return new MainPage(driver);
}

}

public class MainPage{
@FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="mainElement")
private WebElement mainElement;

....

public MainPage(WebDriver driver) {           
         this.driver = driver; 
         PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}


}
```

and than Your test looks like this:

```
   @Test
   public void testLogin(){
      LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
      loginPage.inputUsername(test123);
      MainPage mainPage = loginPage.clickSubmit();
      ...
   }
```

and this is how You could transfer You webDriver across all pages,

Give Yourself time and investigate PageObject Model pattern,

Here is an excellent [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/selenium/test-automation-in-selenium-using-page-object-model-and-page-factory)

Hope I helped...